# Splitting a CSV column wise with no unique delimiters in shell script

Tags: csv, awk, split

I have a CSV with multiple rows some of which look like this

```
"ABC","Unfortunately, system has failed"," - Error in system"
"DEF","Check the button labelled "WARNING"","Warning in system"
"XYZ","Everything is okay","No errors"
```

I need to split these lines and extract the columns such as

[image]

I run a loop for each of the rows and extract the 2nd column as

```
awk -F , '{print $2}' $line
```

where `$line` represents each row. However, I end up getting incorrect values. For example, while trying to fetch 1st row 2nd column, using the above command gives me `"Unfortunately`
and not `"Unfortunately, system has failed"`

I understand that my strings have both commas and quotes in them which makes it harder to split based on a delimiter. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is this valid in any CSV dialect, I wonder? Properly the embedded double quotes should be escaped somehow. Usually this is done by doubling them, like `"Check the button labelled ""WARNING"""`. (Yeah, it's ugly, but then it would be; it's from Microsoft.)

Comment: Running Awk on each line separately is inefficient and ugly. Just run it on the whole file; that's what it was built for (and the shell does a much worse job at splitting input into lines). Also, [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I would expect the input to have escaped double quotes. Unfortunately, the input is sent from a different application, and we don't have a way to control the format they send

Comment: If you don't have GNU Awk, you can use `sed` to decorate each line (i.e. replace `","` with some other separator character) and then use `awk` to parse the 2nd field and restore the enclosing quotes with concatenation, e.g. `sed 's/","/~/g' file.csv | awk -F~ '{print "\"" $2 "\""}'` -- using `'~'` as the decoration.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - How would you know which comma to replace? It could either be the comma separating the columns, or a comma included within the string

Comment: By replacing the entire pattern `"\",\""` with `'~'` -- you know which to replace `:)`

Comment: Duh oh! You're right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk and `FPAT`:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
    print $2
}' file
```

Output:

```
"Unfortunately, system has failed"
"Check the button labelled "WARNING""
"Everything is okay"
```

It's not complete CSV parser, for example newlines inside quotes are not handled, you need to deal with them yourself (check `NF` and combine records). More about `FPAT`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

If you want to get rid of those quotes:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # loop all fields
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i)       # remove quotes surrounding fields
    print $2
}' file
```

Output sample:

```
...
Check the button labelled "WARNING"
...
```

Comment: How did you get this output? I tried the same command you suggested and the output I get is 
`system
the
is`

Comment: Then you probably don't have GNU Awk.

Comment: @CluelessProgrammer what does your `awk --version` report? If it doesn't report GNU Awk -- then `FPAT` likely isn't supported.

Comment: Gotta say, I was a bit surprised that `"WARNING"` came along.

Comment: @tripleee - I did an npm install for gawk and got + gawk@4.7.1

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin awk version 20070501

Comment: Using `npm` to install Unix utilities is decidedly weird. Are you sure you really installed Awk? Seems to be unrelated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gawk

Comment: `awk version 20070501` looks like you have a Mac, and no GNU Awk installed.

Comment: Huh. Weird. Let me verify I actually have it. Gimme a sec

Comment: @tripleee - You're right. Using `npm` to install `gawk` was a wrong move. I used `brew` now and indeed `gawk` is correctly installed. This is something new I learned.

Comment: @JamesBrown - Your script works flawlessly now. Cannot thank you enough. Gotta read up more on `FPAT` and `gawk`. I was only used to `awk` commands all these days

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put your input data in a 3x3 table
you can do it with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS=',[^ ]' -v OFS="|" '{print $1, $2, $3}' file
ABC"|Unfortunately, system has failed"| - Error in system"
"DEF"|Check the button labelled "WARNING""|Warning in system"
"XYZ"|Everything is okay"|No errors"
```

the code:

- why setting `FS=',[^ ]'`? Just that comma in `, system` is not a separator.

Comment: Still not 100% robust, but I like the delimiter you've chosen